# aws dynamodb query error: Query key condition not supported

Tags: amazon-web-services

Here is my question:
I read from amazon dynamodb api that the condition **IN** for query means **Checks for matching elements in a list*, but why it returns an error : **Query key condition not supported**?

*aws dynamodb query --table-name Music --key-conditions '{"Artist": {"AttributeValueList": [{ "S": "Wangdong"}, {"S":"Acme Band"} ], "ComparisonOperator": "IN"  }}' --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000*

An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query key condition not supported

Comment: As the **--key-conditions** is a legacy parameter, I think there is no need to  get to the bottom for **IN** condition

Answer (score 2):

That is because it is a [legacy parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/query.html):

> --key-conditions (map)
>
> This is a legacy parameter. Use KeyConditionExpression instead. For more information, see key-conditions in the Amazon DynamoDB Developer Guide

Look instead into using `--key-condition-expression` as per the documentation (sorry there's no HTML element ID so I can't direct link to it).

Comment: Hello Chris, Thanks for ur answer:)

Comment: Hello Chris, Thanks for ur answer, but I am still confused because I read the Dev Guide and Reference Guide and find the **--key-condition-expression** can only do once equality test for **Partition Key** and **Sorted Key**, not a *IN* test in en array. So what is the point of **IN** condition?

Answer (score 0):

As the **--key-conditions** is a *legacy parameter*, I think there is no need to get to the bottom for **IN** condition.